# Не получается спарсить JSON, jquery + php

Tags: php, jquery, json

Вместо тысячи слов:

```
<style> 
    .stats{
        display: inline-block;
    }
</style>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div id="id" class="stats"></div> <div id="status" class="stats"></div>
    <!-- [{"status_id":"1","status":"1","status_text":"Working","percentage":"100","additional_info":"","last_log_time":"2016-01-24 12:47:52"}] -->
    <script>
    function show_status()
    {
        $.ajax({

        url: "get_status.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: { show_status: "true" },
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){
            //$("#status").html("status is:" + html);
            alert(html);
            var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(html);
            alert(obj.status_text);
            $("#status").html(obj.status_text);
            $("#id").html(obj.id);
        }
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
        show_status();  
        setInterval('show_status()', 5000);  
    });
    </script>
```

Первый алерт нормально выводит json-строку, но после парсинга второй алерт выводи undefined. Почему так происходит и как правильно это сделать? Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[{"status_id":"1","status_text":"Working"}]
```

Обратите внимание на внешние квадратные скобки, они означают, что у вас массив, содержащий один объект. Соответственно обращение должно идти как:

```
alert(obj[0].status_text);
```

Или, если вы уверены, что элемент всегда один, делайте так:

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(html)[0];
alert(obj.status_text);
```

Comment: Да, действительно! Но как мне объяснить что передается не массив а один оюъект? На стороне скрипта ассоциативный массив пакуется так: echo json_encode($data);

Comment: Надо видеть как ваш объект выглядит в php. Ибо `$a=array("abc"=>1, "cde"=>2); echo json_encode($a);` у меня выводит `{"abc":1,"cde":2}` т.е. без квадратных скобок. А для получения скобок приходится объявлять его как `$a=array(array("abc"=>1, "cde"=>2));`

Comment: в самом деле, мой косяк. Спасибо!